# ASMX schema varies when using WCF Service

Tags: asmx, wcf

I have a client (created using ASMX "Add Web Reference"). The service is WCF. The signature of the methods varies for the client and the Service. I get some unwanted parameteres to the method.

Note: I have used IsRequired = true for DataMember.

```
Service:    [OperationContract]
            int GetInt();

Client:     proxy.GetInt(out requiredResult, out resultBool);
```

Could you please help me to make the schame non-varying in both WCF clinet and non-WCF client? Do we have any best practices for that?

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace SimpleLibraryService
{
        [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Lijo.Samples")]
        public interface IElementaryService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            int GetInt();

            [OperationContract]
            int SecondTestInt();
        }

        public class NameDecorator : IElementaryService
        {
            [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
            int resultIntVal = 1;

            int firstVal = 1;

            public int GetInt()
            {
                return firstVal;
            }

            public int SecondTestInt()
            {
                return resultIntVal;
            }
        }

}
```

Binding = "basicHttpBinding"

```
using NonWCFClient.WebServiceTEST;

namespace NonWCFClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NonWCFClient.WebServiceTEST.NameDecorator proxy = new NameDecorator();

            int requiredResult =0;
            bool resultBool = false;
            proxy.GetInt(out requiredResult, out resultBool);
            Console.WriteLine("GetInt___"+requiredResult.ToString() +"__" + resultBool.ToString());

            int secondResult =0;
            bool secondBool = false;
            proxy.SecondTestInt(out secondResult, out secondBool);
            Console.WriteLine("SecondTestInt___" + secondResult.ToString() + "__" + secondBool.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help..

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do much to make this "non-varying" - that's just the way the ASMX client side stuff gets generated from the WCF service. Each client-side stack is a bit different from the other, and might interpret the service contract in the WSDL in a slightly different manner. Not much you can do about that.....

If you don't want this - create a WCF client instead.

A remark on the side:

```
public class NameDecorator : IElementaryService
{
   [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
   int resultIntVal = 1;
```

This is **very strange** how you're trying to put a `DataMember` (a field that should be serialized across for the service) into the class that **implements** the service.....

You should keep your service contract (interface `IElementaryService`), service implementation (class `NameDecorator`) and your data contracts (other classes) separate - do **not** mix data contract and service implementation - this is sure to backfire somehow....